# Zapier Firebase markup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm attempting to link my Zapier account to my Firebase account to trigger once a new entry is seen within a collection.

I've been having issues with this, and I think this is because of the query I'm using:

```
"orderBy": [{
    "field": {
        "fieldPath": "startDateInMilliseconds"
    },
    "direction": "DESCENDING"
}]
```

(this is the default example given in documentation, with my field filled in). I believe the issue stems from the fieldPath, as the field for the collection I'm ordering by is under a subcategory "d".

[Here's a picture of the data that works with the above query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g47Vk.png)

[image]

[He's a picture of the data I'm working with, this one does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHXWI.png)

[image]

[Image with the start date field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YnHN.png)

Without this subcategory, the query works fine in testing, but within this category, the query returns an error, saying it's unable to find any documents.

Does anyone know how to change the query to work for my situation? Thanks.

Comment: Definitely edit the question to describe the data you're trying to query.

Comment: Done, I added screenshots of what I'm working with. The "dateInMilliseconds" field is within the subcategory "d" as seen in the second image.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect the second document to match, since it doesn't have a `dateInMilliseconds` field.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, the second document has a dateInMilliseconds field below the screenshot. I was stressing the subcategory, "d". I can update the screenshot to include that if you need to see it.

Comment: Can you add link to documentation you are referring to in "example given in documentation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to query a property of the `d` field map, you will need to use dot notation to find it.

```
"orderBy": [{
    "field": {
        "fieldPath": "d.dateInMilliseconds"
    },
    "direction": "DESCENDING"
}]
```